# How do I get an oAuth web token from the browser to my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There are lots of questions asking how to open the browser from VS Code. But I'm looking for the opposite thing. I have an oAuth token that I'm console logging on the browser, and want to store it on VS Code.

I have a very simple "Login with GitHub" app. Right now it executes all the oAuth flow correctly, and I can print the web token on the browser's console.

However, I don't see much material about how to this. I want to store the token on the user's VS Code session so that he can use the app, which calls Github's API on the background.

**EDIT**

The other option I am contemplating is using the webview that I already have on VS Code and try to pop up Github there. Like this, which works totally fine on Google Chrome:

```
OAuth.popup('github').then(github => {
    console.log(github);
    // Retrieves user data from oauth provider
    console.log(github.me());
});
```

However, no pop up happens